# Listbox doubleclick to followhyperlink

Tags: hyperlink, double-click

I have a listbox named Tableau in which I have 6 columns. I wrote a function that is supposed to send me to the web hyperlink when I click the request number (colunm 3 value), it opens the hyperlink that I gave to it.

I want it to add the request number that is located in the colunm 3 of the listbox to the end of the link to complete the web adress.
(ex: "www.google.com" & request_id from listbox)

I wrote the following but nothing seems to happen when I click the number from colunm 2

Dbclick code for listbox:

```js
Private Sub tableau_DbClick(ByVal Cancel As msforms.ReturnBoolean)
                                                
  On Error GoTo errhandler                                                                                                                    
  Application.FollowHyperlink "https://infogeo3.vsj.ca/io/Ionis/Requete2/Edit?requete_id=" & tableau.List(tableau.ListIndex, 2)
                                                                                                                      
End Sub
```

[Image of the interference where Table listbox is at the bottom.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erlqu.png)

Comment: Code hidden in an image is not a good idea. Please update your question with written code.

Comment: I wrote the code for the dbclick. However I can`t put the listbox image as a code.